# How to disable DVD drive after boot, but with easy revive

Tags: windows-7

Acer Aspire V5-571-6726, Windows 7 Pro

Every time I open an explorer window, my cd/dvd drive starts spinning or parking for a while (nothing's in it) and overall it just hogs precious battery power.

I still want to keep it on during POST just in case, but is there a registry function to disable it temporarily?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this will work but try this:
Device Manager
Right click and disable.
[image]

Comment: Yes, this will work; I forgot about it.